# Calculating the swipe distance using touchesBegan and touchesEnded

Tags: ios, objective-c, touchesbegan, cgpoint

I am able to find the x,y location on the iPhone screen using a method similar to: [How to get a CGPoint from a tapped location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556120/how-to-get-a-cgpoint-from-a-tapped-location).  However, since TouchesBegan and TouchesEnded require void, I am unable to return there locations directly and use in a different method to calculate the distance.  The distance method I am trying to use is:

```
- (CGFloat) calculateDistanceBetweenPoint1: (CGPoint)start point2:(CGPoint)end
{
    CGFloat dx = end.x - start.x;
    CGFloat dy = end.y - start.y;
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

where end is the coordinate using touchesEnded and start is the coordinate using touchesBegan.  Once I find the distance in pixels I will then convert it to inches or centimeters.  Any suggestions?

Comment: "return there locations directly"?? what do you mean? why not just save the value in a ivar

Comment: Under both the -(void)touchesBegan... and -(void)touchesEnded methods the locations are saved as currentLoc.location.x and currentLoc.location.y, where location is a CGPoint.  I want to use these locations in the method entered in my question.  I am new to objective-c and I am continually getting "Unused variable" errors or hiding instance variable errors.  Can you give an example of what I should declare in my header file and how I should implement the ivar?  Note, all 3 of these methods are in the same class file.  I would really appreciate it!