# In ScrollableGraphView, how to detect dot click from line graph and bar click from bar graph?

Tags: ios, swift3, linegraph

I already implemented **ScrollableGraphView** in my app, but I am not getting how to add label with value on click of "Dot" and/or "Bar". Please refer image.

[image: Line Graph with label]

and

[image: Bar graph with label]

Till now I able to achieve everything without label. This is best library.
But now I am not getting how to detect touch/click of Dot and/or Bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify point of Tap via **CGPoint** : that will give X and Y Coordinates.

**Location Reference:** [How to get a CGPoint from a tapped location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556120/how-to-get-a-cgpoint-from-a-tapped-location)

For the label you want to show on tap, you have to 
create a custom view using **XIB** and **Invoke** 
it in Tap gesture **Action/Selector**.