# Detect Touch Events on Keyboard on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, keyboard-events

I would like to detect touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesCancelled, and touchesEnded when using the keyboard on the iPhone.

Is there any way to get the UITouch? I would like to get the location of the touch on the keyboard.

Comment: the general way to get touch event location anywhere is listed below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556120/how-to-get-a-cgpoint-from-a-tapped-location You probably need to change "anyObject" to the keyboard object, but not sure how

Comment: @n4feng Thank you. However, I want to be able to detect touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesCancelled, and touchesEnded.

Comment: That is fine, you should be able to override the handler of the UITouch object. For example [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];